# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources' AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, gradle

I need help with a project I am working on, the thing is everything was working fine a few days back, but then I had to travel now when I try to run the command react-native run-android I received the following error

```
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

> Android resource linking failed

C:\Users\sarat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b5c19e49f776b182a5792cfc47bb4d7e\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

I suggest you to check your drawable folders by theme.